# ASP.Net Web API - Find the Correct URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api, entity

This might be a bit of a simple question. I have implemented a scaffolded controller for a Web API but can't seem to find the right url to hit it in a browser.

The controller is called ComputerAddController.cs

I've tried:

```
http://localhost:port/api/ComputerAdd/2
http://localhost:port/api/ComputerAdd
http://localhost:port/ComputerAdd/api/2
http://localhost:port/ComputerAdd/api
```

Any direction would be much appreciated (the DB/Model has definitely got an existing entry at id 2)

My Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Inbound
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Inbound
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
public class ComputerAddController : ApiController
    {
        private InboundModel db = new InboundModel();

        // GET: api/ComputerAdd
        public IQueryable<tbl_computerinfo_staging> Gettbl_computerinfo_staging()
        {
            return db.tbl_computerinfo_staging;
        }

        // GET: api/ComputerAdd/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(tbl_computerinfo_staging))]
        public IHttpActionResult Gettbl_computerinfo_staging(int id)
        {
            tbl_computerinfo_staging tbl_computerinfo_staging = db.tbl_computerinfo_staging.Find(id);
            if (tbl_computerinfo_staging == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(tbl_computerinfo_staging);
        }
```

Comment: Specify [HttpGet] above the controller method.

Comment: @Kumar, it has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this. Apparently in the global.asax.cs, the WebApiConfig.Register needs to be placed above the RouteConfig.Register routes:

global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;

    namespace Inbound
    {
        public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
        {
            protected void Application_Start()
            {
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
                RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            }
        }
    }
```